# C# .NET Emails are not being sent in Production, but work in Test

Tags: c#, twilio, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

Our test enviroment is deployed to Azure, and it does send the emails. While the Production, doesn't. The API key is set and it's the same as test one. What can it be?

```
    public async Task<Response> SendEmailAsync(
      SendGridMessage msg,
      CancellationToken cancellationToken = default (CancellationToken))
    {
      return await this.RequestAsync(SendGridClient.Method.POST, msg.Serialize(), urlPath: "mail/send", cancellationToken: cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }


    public async Task<Response> RequestAsync(
      SendGridClient.Method method,
      string requestBody = null,
      string queryParams = null,
      string urlPath = null,
      CancellationToken cancellationToken = default (CancellationToken))
    {
      string uriString = this.client.BaseAddress.ToString() + this.BuildUrl(urlPath, queryParams);
      StringContent stringContent = (StringContent) null;
      if (requestBody != null)
        stringContent = new StringContent(requestBody, Encoding.UTF8, this.MediaType);
      return await this.MakeRequest(new HttpRequestMessage()
      {
        Method = new HttpMethod(method.ToString()),
        RequestUri = new Uri(uriString),
        Content = (HttpContent) stringContent
      }, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```

I double checked API keys, and it's set. While I don't have access to Azure, I can still access logs, and there is no error coming from SendGrid, but no emails are being sent in Production. While Test environment works perfectly fine

Comment: " I can still access logs,"  which logs? You application logs or sendgrid logs? Sendgrid itself should have some log of sent mails. Do your production emails show up there? Do you have any application logs that suggest there actually was a request to sendgrid in your production environment?

Comment: Log on to your Sendgrid account, see if emails are arriving there.

Comment: Just an FYI, there's a method called `SendEmailAsync` in the SendGrid SDK that will also send the email. It's a little simpler than programming the API calls yourself, but either work fine.

Comment: As sugested above, I'd take a look at the [Email Activity Feed](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/analytics-and-reporting/email-activity-feed) in the SendGrid app to see if you SendGrid messages show up, and if they do, why they aren't delivered.
If they don't show up, then the messages aren't submitted to the SendGrid API properly.

Comment: It can literally be anything, but in case it's useful to anyone I'll share my story. We were using an Office 365 mailbox but had instances in multiple geographies. Apparently this sets off a flag which no one could figure out how to prevent. Now we use SES and have never had a problem.

Comment: Also, how do you know they aren't being and blocked by your email provider? I have had that happen with Sendgrid many, many times, because in the standard config you share a source IP with other users, meaning if they abuse it you get blocked too.

Comment: Sorry one more. If you're not already doing so you really should be catching and logging exceptions raised by the final send method which you don't appear to show. If the SMTP server is rejecting it the Exception should tell you why. Again, learned this from experience, and I don't think any Azure log will tell you about these kinds of exceptions. (Unless you're on a VM and can check the Event Viewer).